# Scroll to error component using formik react native

Tags: react-native, formik

I don't know how create a component which can scroll to error using formik in my app  because my form is big and I want to scroll to input with error to make app better.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import { useFormikContext } from 'formik';

const ScrollToError = () => {
  const formik = useFormikContext();
  const submitting = formik?.isSubmitting;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (formik?.errors && submitting) {
      const keys = Object.keys(formik.errors);
      const firstErrorKey = keys[0];
      const firstError = formik?.getFieldProps(firstErrorKey)?.ref?.current;
      if (firstError) {
        firstError.focus();
      }
    }
  }, [formik, submitting]);
  return null;
};

export default ScrollToError;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the y position of every input and a reference to the view.

```
  const refScrollView = useRef<ScrollView>(null);
  const [fieldsPositions, setFieldsPositions] = useState({
    nameField: 0,
    emailField: 0,
    xyzField: 0,
  });
```

To get the y position you can use the *onLayout* prop.

Example for the email field:

```
onLayout={(event: LayoutChangeEvent) =>
  setFieldsPositions({
    nameField: fieldsPositions.nameField,
    emailField: event.nativeEvent?.layout?.y, // <-
    xyzField: fieldsPositions.xyzField,
  })
}
```

And when you've got an error ( your *if (firstError)* ) you can scroll down to the field:

```
refScrollView.current.scrollTo({
    x: 0,
    y: fieldsPositions.email,
    animated: true,
});
```